# how to load files in https in my site

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, http, https

i have this inside google chrome console

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v14/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTa-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
x.fn.offset @ 1-10-2-jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ 1-11-3-jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ 1-11-3-jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ 1-11-3-jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ 1-11-3-jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ 1-11-3-jquery-ui.min.js:6
```

when i open the javascript file it dosn`t contain any fonts or http . 
i want to load fonts in https . can this happend with htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm completely missing the point -- very possible -- just use the https equivalent: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v14/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTa-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2

Comment: the font loaded by the JavaScript file as i think but the problem is its loaded in http not https

Comment: right -- so, are you able to change that "http" to "https" in the url?

Comment: no the problem is that its loaded with out http or even url

Comment: You can't load something without a URL, the fonts are most likely coming from a CSS that's got the URL, seen as it's Google fonts, you just change the link style to use   https://